# DBIx::Class test agains mysql datetime function

Tags: mysql, perl, datetime, catalyst, dbix-class

I am using [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class) and I would like to select rows based on what day of the year they were inserted on. Below is my query:

```
$rows = $c->model("DB::Test")->search(
{
    "DAYOFYEAR(entry_time)"=>$day_of_year,
});
```

However this doesn't work because DBIx::Class treats `DAYOFYEAR(entry_time)` as a column. Is there anyway I could have it use that value litteraly? I know sometimes making it a scalar such as `\'DAYOFYEAR(entry_time)'` will work for some situations, but I've tried that and it doesn't work. Does anyone know of a way that I could do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `\` and `'DAYOFYEAR(entry_time)'` is the right approach, and part of the [FAQ](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class::Manual::FAQ).

> [How do I] **.. search with an SQL function on the left hand side?**
>
> To use an SQL function on the left hand side of a comparison you currently need to resort to literal SQL:

```
->search( \[ 'YEAR(date_of_birth) = ?', [ plain_value => 1979 ] ] );
```

> Note: the `plain_value` string in the `[ plain_value => 1979 ]` part should be either the same as the name of the column (do this if the type of the return value of the function is the same as the type of the column) or in the case of a function it's currently treated as a dummy string (it is a good idea to use `plain_value` or something similar to convey intent). The value is currently only significant when handling special column types (BLOBs, arrays, etc.), but this may change in the future.